# ddrescue: safely switch between normal/reverse with a logfile?

Tags: hard-drive, ddrescue

I'm trying to rescue a broken harddrive with:

```
sudo ddrescue -d -r3 /dev/sda harddisk.img harddisk.logfile
```

(yes, it's indeed sda because my sATA cables are weird)

Now I've read that ddrescue has a reverse option. Can safely do the following without corrupting my image and logfile:

```
sudo ddrescue -d -r3 -R /dev/sda harddisk.img harddisk.logfile
```

Can I switch back and forth between the two reading modes?

Answer (score 1):

Too bad you didn't get answers sooner.

I would say yes (if it's safe to use -R at all then it should be safe to alternate between normal and reverse copying), but I'm actually trying this right now so I won't know for sure until I finish and begin exploring the output... It's only the second time I try to recover a HD with ddrescue. This one is tricky as it keeps disappearing or ceases to respond whenever there's a bad block, so far copying in reverse mode turns out much better, as most errors seem to be at the begining, but I already had to switch it off and on several times.

Maybe you tried it yourself since you asked ? What I'm wondering is how it gets written to the destination drive, since about midway through the recovery the image file size was half the total size of the source, even though I had already used -R (which should have begun at the very end, thus resulting in the image file having the exact same size as the source).